# Webpack2 and angular templates - handling images and other resources which names unknown at compilation time

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-2

Okay, now let's say I have Angular2 application and webpack2:

```
//webpack.config.js:
....
module: { 
    rules:[
        //typescript compilation
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use:[
                {
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
                }
            ],
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        },
        //templates compilation
        {
            test: /\.template\.html$/,
            use:[
                {
                    loader: 'html-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        //image processing
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
            use:[
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In one of my Angular components I have defined a templateUrl property which leads to this simple template:

```
<div class="waiting">
    <img src="../images/ripple.gif">
</div>
```

As a result, after webpack done it's job I indeed have "images" folder with
this file. The folder is situated on the same level with compiled app.js.
It works as expected, no problem here.

In another Angular component I have another template (surprise, surprise). Here is a part of this template:

```
....
<td >
    <img [src]="'./../../images/cards' + row.cardDesignCode + '.png'">
</td>
....
```

As far as I can understand, webpack and it's loaders can't parse this properly, because it doesn't know resource url in compilation time. I would like webpack to place images from my "cards" subfolder (which is inside "images" folder). And it would be the best to have him create this subfolder as well on build process.
I know there is interpolation option in html-loader, but I would like to avoid any explicit require statements.

Could anyone tell me the best approach how to handle this situation? 
Of course I can put the folder manually, but maybe there are other options? It's hard to believe that nobody ever tried to automate this.

Comment: hi what if you try something like this in your webapck file: //},
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
                //include:  path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/img"),
                loader: 'file?name=/assets/img/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
            },

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me, unfortunately

Comment: also if you remove the .. and put in 'file?name=/assets/img/ the right put where gulp put your images?

Comment: sorry i mean webpack :-)

Answer (score 0):

CopyWebpackPlugin has answered my needs. Not quite what I have asked but works for now